# Gradients look bad after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I installed Nvidia drivers using additional drivers in Software and updates, then after removing `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` and rebooting, all gradients on my built in screen look pixelated and on my other screen everything is fine,  I think it's a issue with display port but I don't know.

It also happens in videos on youtube, and in programs, How do i fix the issue?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 lts, intel i7 7700hq, and nvidia gtx 1070 in a laptop.

Comment: What is wrong with the background? I didn't see any problem. It looks the same as the official image here https://launchpadlibrarian.net/244020606/Xerus_Wallpaper_4096x2304.png

Comment: I have updated the question and I see the gradient of the picture you sent as pixelated.

Comment: Screenshots probably aren't affected by the problem so that's why it looked fine to dragon2fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to install latest Nvidia drivers are

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-
```

then press `tab` to show the list of candidates. You should see many `nvidia-xxx` where `xxx` is a 3 digit number. Then, find the biggest number!

For example if it is `361`, your last command will be

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

Installing latest driver could fix many problems including your.

update:

1. Open `NVIDIA X Server Settings`
2. select `LGD (DP-0)` or something similar.
3. select the `Controls` tab on the right panel
4. Enable `Dithering` option

Comment: It don't work I installed nvidia-352 and when I try to install nvidia-361 it says you already have it.

Comment: @TheGathron What is the biggest number that you see? `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`, then install the latest again

Comment: I have installed nvidia-378 which is the latest version and the problem still exits

Comment: @TheGathron Did you restart your computer?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my computer. I also found out it effects my built in display not any monitors.

Comment: @TheGathron Can you open `NVIDIA X Server Settings` and check if there is `DFP-1` under `GPU 0`?

Comment: No, under display devices there is LGD (DP-0) benq (HDMI-0)

Comment: @TheGathron what tab does it has on the right panel? `Control`? `Color correction`?

Comment: going to DP-0 there is both controls and color correction

Comment: I found to solution I changed dithering from disabled to enabled

Comment: @TheGathron I'm about to tell you to do that. Glad that helped you.